# Can't load shared library libQt5Core.so.5

Tags: qt, debian, shared-libraries, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This question has been asked before, but the fixes don't work for me. I am running Windows 10 with WSL (Debian) and I am unable to run a QT program because of the error

`texconv: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I found [a post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034313/ubuntu-18-4-libqt5core-so-5-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-dir) which discusses the same problem. I've tried tolos' and Envek's solutions, but they don't work for me. For me the file is under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` like tolos' was. I also sudo-ed the strip and recompiled the qt program (If that even matters), but it still doesn't work.

If it matters, my kernel version (checked with `uname -r`) is 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft and I have no issues running this qt program on my other PC that uses WSL Ubuntu. And I installed the qt stuff with this command: `sudo apt-get install qt5-default qtbase5-dev`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got it working in the end. I upgraded from WSLv1 to WSLv2 and that solved it. Not sure why, but it must have been a WSLv1 Debian bug

Comment: in WSL1 you have to: `sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
`

Comment: thanks it worked in my case

`okular: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: @s.ouchene: thanks man, it worked on my WSL 1.0

Comment: @k3nn: For details, please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64594256/5920411

Comment: Worked in WSL1 to make `lyx` run.  I never had problem until big batch of updates ran last week.  Guess I learned my lesson!

Comment: Also worked in WSL 1 Ubuntu to compile [Granoo](https://www.granoo.org/install.html). I just updated it to WSL 2.

Answer (score 28):

I had an image that I would run using **docker run** and which would successfully launch KStars -- an application that uses this `libQt5core.so.5`.

If I ran the very same image on a **Kubernetes** cluster then I would get an error message when launching KStars like `libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` or some such.

Putting this `strip` command into the Dockerfile and rebuilding the image allowed the application to load successfully in both environments.

```
sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

Comment: My path was slightly different on WSL1 running Fedora. I did `find /usr -name libQt5Core.so.5` to get the `QT_PATH`, then `sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag "$QT_PATH"`. Works like a charm!