# paraview: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: paraview, openfoam

I installed OpenFOAM on Ubuntu (which is itself on WSL Windows Subsystem for Linux).
I have a problem when trying to launch `paraFoam` and I have this error :

```
Invalid $PV_PLUGIN_PATH and -plugin-path= not defined
No supplementary ParaView/OpenFOAM reader modules
Using builtin reader: paraFoam -vtk

paraview: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It seems that it comes from paraview or Qt but I don't know what to do.
The file `libQt5Core.so.5` does exist in the computer

When I type `qmake --version` I have

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.12.8 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: @Navaro yes I am

Comment: yes thank you. It worked, I just have som Qt problems to fix now

Comment: Just as a side note: It's not necessary to have Paraview installed on WSL. You can install a Windows version of Paraview instead and use it to open the case files with `.foam` extension.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are using WSL1, this issue is common. you can solve it by running the following command:

```
sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

To solve the issue related to the GLIBCXX, try:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /opt/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v2006/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: I have now others errors which say ```/opt/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v2006/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26'```
I tried to do ```sudo apt-get update``` and ```sudo apt-get upgrade``` but it doesn't change anything

Comment: This seems to be relevant for Qt6 as well on WSL 1--I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why `qmake` and friends could not find `libQt6Core.so.6` despite it obviously existing in my `/path/to/Qt6/lib` directory. Is this no longer an issue for WSL 2?

Comment: @phetdam: Yes, I believe this is no longer an issue for WSL2.

Comment: @AlexV.: You can make a backup copy of libQt5Core.so.5.15.3 and run the strip command against it.

Comment: @AlexV. I believe the comment section might not be the best place to resolve this issue. Please consider asking a new question for a more effective solution